# Joomla module visible in article but not in category

Tags: php, css, joomla, joomla3.0

I have a problem with Joomla!. Is there a way to set a module visible in certain category but not in the articles? (so it will display on the category page, but not in the articles of that category or in subcategories)
I had the oposite problem on previous works and fixed it with some cat id's and php in the index.php, but I don't know how to achieve this effect, is someone there that had the same problem and fixed it?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a override of the category view in template/your_template/html/ folder and use the following code inside the override file :

```
<?php
$document = JFactory::getDocument();
$renderer = $document->loadRenderer('modules');
$position = "YOURPOSITIONNAME";
$options = array('style' => 'raw');
echo $renderer->render($position, $options, null);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this useful ?
I don't develop on Joomla, but i found this link.

http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/joomla-25/extensions/modules-on-homepage

Answer (score 0):

Why not use Advanced Module Manager which has several advanced options that will suit your requirement https://www.regularlabs.com/extensions/advancedmodulemanager#free-vs-pro .